# Can't open live server with ReactJS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-redux, react-router

```
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
    at module.exports (D:\ReactJS\JavaScript Mastery\crypto_app\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:90:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (D:\ReactJS\JavaScript Mastery\crypto_app\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:386:16)
    at handleParseError (D:\ReactJS\JavaScript Mastery\crypto_app\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:434:10)
    at D:\ReactJS\JavaScript Mastery\crypto_app\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:466:5
    at D:\ReactJS\JavaScript Mastery\crypto_app\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:327:12
    at D:\ReactJS\JavaScript Mastery\crypto_app\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:373:3
    at iterateNormalLoaders (D:\ReactJS\JavaScript Mastery\crypto_app\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (D:\ReactJS\JavaScript Mastery\crypto_app\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:221:10)
    at D:\ReactJS\JavaScript Mastery\crypto_app\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:236:3
    at runSyncOrAsync (D:\ReactJS\JavaScript Mastery\crypto_app\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:130:11)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (D:\ReactJS\JavaScript Mastery\crypto_app\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:232:2)
    at Array.<anonymous> (D:\ReactJS\JavaScript Mastery\crypto_app\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:205:4)
    at Storage.finished (D:\ReactJS\JavaScript Mastery\crypto_app\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:55:16)
    at D:\ReactJS\JavaScript Mastery\crypto_app\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:91:9
D:\ReactJS\JavaScript Mastery\crypto_app\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js:19
  throw err;
  ^

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
    at module.exports (D:\ReactJS\JavaScript Mastery\crypto_app\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:90:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (D:\ReactJS\JavaScript Mastery\crypto_app\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:386:16)
    at D:\ReactJS\JavaScript Mastery\crypto_app\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:418:10
    at D:\ReactJS\JavaScript Mastery\crypto_app\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:293:13
    at D:\ReactJS\JavaScript Mastery\crypto_app\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at D:\ReactJS\JavaScript Mastery\crypto_app\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:233:18
    at context.callback (D:\ReactJS\JavaScript Mastery\crypto_app\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at D:\ReactJS\JavaScript Mastery\crypto_app\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:51:103 {
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}
```

I have errors like this in my terminal. I can't reach the page display my ReactJS project. Does anyone know how to fix this?? Please help me out. Thank you.

I tried many solutions on stackoverflow.com but i still have my trouble. I expect to fix this error.

Comment: can you please share `package.json` file ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to understand first, how reactjs works.

1. You are writing the components which return `JSX` not `html` and live server runs on `html` files.
2. React.Js is a library of JavaScript which have soo many functions, packages, method which is not written by you and you need to compile the resources.

by using `npm run start` (if you're using `npx create-react-app`)

or using `npm run dev` (if you're using `npm create vite@latest`)

These command the compile your code into `html` `css` and `javascript` and create a custom `live server` which runs on `http:localhost:3000` Or `http://localhost:5173` you don't need any live server.

3. After you run this command `npm run build` your project is compile for `production` which you can deploy on `netlify` or any other hosting.

You can see an `build` or `dist` name folder is created automatically and you can start the live server on it.